# Edit Table Column Header

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-table

I wanted to know if there is any way we can edit the column headers of a mat-table and store the new value in some variable. I haven't found a satisfactory answer anywhere to this.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily edit the column headers of a table and store the new value in some variable as follows:

### .html file

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>{{heading1}}</th>
    <th>{{heading2}}</th>
    <th>{{heading3}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### .ts file

```
heading1 = 'Test1';
heading2 = 'Test2';
heading3 = 'Test3';
```

Now, the table heading will be `Test1`, `Test2` and `Test3`. So, now if you change the `heading1` variable to `'Heading 1'`. The Table's first heading will be changed to `Heading 1`.

---

There are lots of efficient and cleaner way to do the same.
Do read this: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview